# Dynamically create new line breaks(<br>) using $A.createComponent and aura:html

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Im trying to dynamically create custom text spinner in lightning component. But I see the that the text is overlapping. Below is the what is what I have so far.

[image]

Markup:

```
<div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
    <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium slds-is-relative" role="alert">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        <div aura:id="spinnerTextDiv">
            <!--{!v.body}-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller.js:

```
    helper.handleSpinnerTextDynamically(cmp,'Creating renewal Opportunities ...');

    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            if(cmp.isValid()){
                helper.handleSpinnerTextDynamically(cmp,'Creating renewal Quotes ...');
            }
        }), 2000);
```

helper.Js

```
handleSpinnerTextDynamically : function(cmp,textBody) {
    $A.createComponents([
            ["aura:html",{
                'tag': 'p',
                'HTMLAttributes':{"style":"transform: translate(-32%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);width: 320px;text-align: center;"},
                'body': textBody
            }],
            ["aura:html",{
                'tag': 'br',
                'HTMLAttributes':''
            }]
        ],
        function(components, status){
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var paragraphElement = components[0];
                var spinnerTextDiv = cmp.find('spinnerTextDiv').get('v.body');
                spinnerTextDiv.push(paragraphElement);
                cmp.find('spinnerTextDiv').set('v.body', spinnerTextDiv);//.concat(paragraphElement)
            }
        }
    );
}
```

As you can see in the above image the text **Creating renewal Opportunities** and **Creating renewal Quote** is over lapping. What I'm looking for is something like below.

```
Creating renewal Opportunities .. 
Creating renewal Quote ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform is moving each new `p` into the exact same space as the previous one. Instead, rotate the entire div that contains the content, then put your content inside of that.

```
<div class="spinnerTextDiv">
  {!v.body}
</div>
```

---

```
.THIS .spinnerTextDiv {
    transform: translate(-32%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
    width: 320px;
}
```

---

```
$A.createComponents([
        ["aura:html",{
            'tag': 'p',
            'HTMLAttributes':'',
            'body': textBody
        }]
    ],
    // rest of code ... //
```

You may need to tweak the code a little bit. Note that `p` should take care of the line breaks for you, so no extra `br` should be required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That worked. But had to align the text to the centre to align with the spinner

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you transform the parent `div` instead of transforming every child div?

```
<div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
        <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-is-relative" role="alert">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            <div class="slds-is-relative">
                <div aura:id="spinnerTextDiv" class="spinner-text" style="{!'left:'+v.noOfDivs+'rem;'}">
                    <!--{!v.body}-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
.THIS .spinner-text {
    position:absolute; 
    transform: translate(-32%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
    width: 320px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also if you are adding multiple divs, you need to take care of positioning it correctly. So, you need to add that height of div every time you add new status (or remove accordingly).

So, use `noOfDivs` for that:

```
handleSpinnerTextDynamically: function(cmp, textBody) {
    $A.createComponents(
        [
            [
                'aura:html',
                {
                    tag: 'div',
                    body: textBody
                }
            ]
        ],
        function(components, status) {
            if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
                let noOfDivs = cmp.get('v.noOfDivs');
                noOfDivs = noOfDivs + 0.6;
                cmp.set('v.noOfDivs', noOfDivs);

                var paragraphElement = components[0];
                var spinnerTextDiv = cmp.find('spinnerTextDiv').get('v.body');
                spinnerTextDiv.push(paragraphElement);
                cmp.find('spinnerTextDiv').set('v.body', spinnerTextDiv); //.concat(paragraphElement)
            }
        }
    );
}
```

[image]

#### if you do not use `noOfDivs`:

[image]

#### Note: I used `noOfDivs` as straight forward solution but you can use any other way to just keep tab on positioning

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.